# xassoccnt : error on loading package

Tags: xassoccnt

I'm trying to switch from `assoccnt` to `xassoccnt` but I get a few errors on loading the package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\begin{document}
bla
\end{document}
```

when I run pdflatex or xelatex I get

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3candidates.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.38 \str_const:Nn
               \c__xassoccnt_modulename_str {xassoccnt}
```

I've tried adding a `\usepackage{l3str}` but then another error message appears:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/property-unknown"
! 
! The key property '.value_forbidden:n' is unknown.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.173 }
```

Any idea ?

Comment: what versions are you running of your compilers and packages? This runs fine here.

Comment: In case of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313454/custom-navigation-dots-in-beamer-headline/313518#comment765978_313518 an upgrade to TeXLive 2016 solved this error (the linked problem is about `xcntperchap` but this internally uses `xcntperchap`, as far as I know).

Comment: I am the author of both `assoccnt` and `xassoccnt` -- you definitely need a newer `expl3` version! Please note that some features of `assoccnt` are not supported by `xassoccnt` (yet)

Comment: I'll try to provide a version that does not use `expl3` features newer than 2015

Comment: Well, this is odd : my linux mint is up to date ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

*There's xassoccnt v1.5 available on CTAN and TL 2017 by now. 
In a future release I will remove any 'old-fashioned' compatibility workarounds regarding `expl3` - features however.
As of writing this (2017/07/29) I have not made a decision, which future version will 'break' older code, however.*

`xassoccnt` uses some features of `expl3` that has been added in 2015, especially the `\str_const:Nn` etc.

I used that features right from the start when I redesigned `assoccnt` to use `expl3` code beginning in October 2015, at that time the used features were available of course (according to the `interface3` documentation, the `\str_const:Nn` code was added on 2015-09-18)

I've uploaded a version `xassoccnt.sty` v.0.9a that uses `\tl` variables instead, which are supported quite a long time by now.

Please note that this is no official release: [xassoccnt09a](http://siebenfelsen.de/xassoccnt-v0-9), in the DropBox folder under `xassoccnt/xassoccnt_0.9a` or directly from DropBox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ckwc8hbr5xeq3v7/xassoccnt.sty?dl=0.

Just place this in a local folder (not in the offical TeX tree)

**Note**: I don't have a pre Sep-2015 TeXLive tree in order to test my proposition!

The easiest way is of course an update of TeXLive etc.

Comment: Still the same error (the second one). But don't bother working on this for me : if it's my TeXlive that needs updating then I will do what's necessary. Thanks !

Comment: @Alexis: You don't need the `l3str` package

Comment: I've commented it out (I added it to try and solve my problem, I've no intention of using it), the problem remains. One again, thanks but don't waste time on this ! I'll update my texlive.

Comment: @Alexis: Alright, please keep me informed