# create a newcounter with starting value and increment the counter on every page

Tags: pdftex, counters, page, xassoccnt

create a new counter with starting value and increment the counter on every page, below code is working in texlive17 but I am using texlive15 so i getting [the error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316432/xassoccnt-error-on-loading-package), is it any alternative solution.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalrealpage}
\NewDocumentCounter{realpage}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{page}{realpage,totalrealpage}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\setcounter{realpage}{30}}\makeatother


\makeatother

\begin{document}

value \therealpage
\newpage
value \therealpage
\newpage
value \therealpage
\newpage
value \therealpage
\newpage
value \therealpage
\newpage

\pagenumbering{gobble}

value \therealpage
\newpage
value \therealpage
\newpage
value \therealpage
\newpage
value \therealpage
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

value \therealpage
\newpage
value \therealpage
\newpage
value \therealpage
\newpage
value \therealpage
\newpage
value \therealpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: why texlive 2015, when you can update to texlive 2019 ? However without any packages you can just declare a counter and then increment it in the page head

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks